# Box constrained optimization - BFGS

Tags: numerical-methods, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have written my own code to implement BFGS method for unconstrained problem(FORTRAN). But now I want to convert the same code for solving box constrained optimization problems. How can I go about to accomplish this using the BFGS method?

Thank you for any help :) .

Comment: Gradient projection method?

Comment: @A.Γ. I just read about it. Thanks a lot, I was looking for something like this. :D

Comment: I had some good experience with the so called L-BFGS-B https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS#L-BFGS-B see for instance https://github.com/PatWie/CppNumericalSolvers

Comment: L-BFGS-B is the best answer to this question.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @A.Γ. I was trying to implement Gradient projection with BFGS. I have merged gradient projection in line search(wolfe) i.e. I am taking the projection for a given alpha(step size) and checking if this new update satisfies the wolfe conditions --> **X(k+1) = PROJ[  X(k) - alpha * Inv_Hess_ *grad(F)   ]** . But if done this way, Line search is not able to find any step size. Is the correct way to do? Any help will be appreciated.